# SQL Server Query to Count Number of Changing Values in a Column Sequentially

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-partitioning

I need to count the number of changing values in a column sequentially. Please see image for illustration (correct or expected output)

In here, the column `Area` is changing, counter column should display the sequential counter based on the changing values in area.

[image]

I have started with this code

```
    SELECT a.tenant, a.area, a.date , a.gsc, f.counter
    FROM TENANT a
        inner join
            (SELECT a.tenant, COUNT(DISTINCT e.Area) AS counter
             FROM TENANT
             GROUP BY tenant
            ) AS f ON a.tenant = f.tenant
   order by a.tenant, a.date
```

And gives me this output. Counting the number of distinct values found in `Area` column IN ALL rows.

[image]

Comment: the query is missing an `ORDER BY` clause so the result is not guaranteed to be ordered: is that an issue? you expect/want the correct result even if the rows are unordered?

Comment: You should determine how the counter is sequential, i.e, why the first two 18  values are considered in order 1, and the two last 18 are in order 3?

Comment: select tenant instead of a.tenant in the sub-query?

Comment: I HAVE EDITED THE IMAGE TABLE sorry and put the order by clause...

Comment: Is this truly a matter of sequential values or more of a matter of Gaps and Islands? https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud It is actually based on the order of the rows.. first 18 is considered 1, and when found different value, it should be 2, and 3 on the last two 18 values because it changes again from 20

Comment: @rickyProgrammer - Is the order of rows based solely on date, or is there another condition as well, ie Date and with a partition for the tenant?

Comment: Based on date per tenant... So each tenant should have a sequential numbering or counter based on date and unique area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using window functions:

```
SELECT tenant, area, [date], sales,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grpOrder) AS counter
FROM (
  SELECT tenant, area, date, sales,       
         MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY area, grp) AS grpOrder
  FROM (
    SELECT tenant, area, [date], sales,           
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY area ORDER BY [date]) AS grp
    FROM tenant ) AS t ) AS s
```

The inner query identifies islands of consecutive `area` values. See `grp` value in below partial output from this sub-query:

```
area date       grp
--------------------
18   2015-01-01  0
18   2015-01-02  0
18   2015-01-05  2
18   2015-01-06  2
20   2015-01-03  2
20   2015-01-04  2
```

Using window version of `MIN` we can calculate `grp` order: field `grpOrder` holds the minimum date per group.

Using `DENSE_RANK()` in the outer query we can now easily calculate `counter` values: first group gets a value of 1, next group a value of 2, etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abc73/2)

Comment: I am actually examining each query in your answer, my question sir is in the inner query How did we come up to the 0,0,2,2,2,2 output in there? and the island of consecutive? what do we mean by that?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer An island is a set of consecutive rows having the same `area` value. First island is `18, 18`, then comes `20, 20` and then `18, 18`. `grp` is used to identify those islands. To understand how `grp` is computed look at the values returned by the two `ROW_NUMBER` functions of the query.

Comment: what if the dates are not in consecutive form?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer How would you, in this case, identify *changing* `area` values? Change, according to your own description, is derived by ascending `date` values. If this is not the case, then how can we tell that `area` values change? There is no inherent order in sql tables. You always need some field to govern row order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with window functions:

```
declare @data table(name varchar(10), area int, dates datetime, sales int)
insert into @data(name, area, dates, sales) values
('Little Asia', 18, '20150101', 10)
, ('Little Asia', 18, '20150102', 20)
, ('Little Asia', 20, '20150103', 30)
, ('Little Asia', 20, '20150104', 10)
, ('Little Asia', 18, '20150105', 20)
, ('Little Asia', 18, '20150106', 30)

Select name, area, dates, sales
    , [counter] = DENSE_RANK() over(order by c)
    , [count] = Count(*) over(partition by n ,c)
From (
    Select name, area, dates, sales, n 
        , c = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by n, dates) - ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by area, n order by dates)
    From (
        Select name, area, dates, sales 
            , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by dates) - ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by area order by dates)
        From @data
    ) as x
) as v
order by dates
```

Output:

```
name        area    dates       sales   counter count
Little Asia 18      2015-01-01  10      1       2
Little Asia 18      2015-01-02  20      1       2
Little Asia 20      2015-01-03  30      2       2
Little Asia 20      2015-01-04  10      2       2
Little Asia 18      2015-01-05  20      3       2
Little Asia 18      2015-01-06  30      3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there is an extra element in the `tenant` column

```
create table #tenant (tenant varchar(20), area int, date date, sales int)
insert into #tenant values
('little asia', 18, '20150101', 10),
('little asia', 18, '20150102', 20),
('little asia', 20, '20150103', 30),
('little asia', 20, '20150104', 10),
('little asia', 18, '20150105', 20),
('little asia', 18, '20150106', 30),
('little', 18, '20150101', 10),
('little', 18, '20150102', 20),
('little', 18, '20150103', 30),
('little', 18, '20150104', 10),
('little', 18, '20150105', 20),
('little', 11, '20150106', 30);
```

The code will be written as follows:

```
/* new code adding tenant*/
SELECT tenant, area, [date], sales,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant ORDER BY tenant, grpOrder) AS counter
FROM (
  SELECT tenant, area, date, sales,       
         MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY tenant, area, grp) AS grpOrder
FROM (
  SELECT tenant, area, [date], sales,           
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant ORDER BY tenant, date) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant, area ORDER BY tenant, [date]) AS grp
FROM #tenant ) AS t ) AS s
order by tenant, date
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is a difference of atleast 1 (@threshold) we you will start a new group.  this will partition by tenant.

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE (
Tenant varchar(20),
Area int,
[date] Date,
Sales int
)
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
('Little Asia',18,'1/1/2015', 10),
('Little Asia',18,'1/2/2015', 20),
('Little Asia',20,'1/3/2015', 30),
('Little Asia',20,'1/4/2015', 10),
('Little Asia',18,'1/5/2015', 20),
('Little Asia',18,'1/6/2015', 30)

/***** Begin Query *****/
DECLARE @Threshold INT = 1
;WITH C1 AS
(
SELECT Tenant, Area, [Date], Sales,
CASE WHEN ABS(Area - LAG(Area) OVER(PARTITION BY Tenant ORDER BY [Date])) <= @Threshold THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS isstart
FROM @Table
 ),
C2 AS
 (
SELECT Tenant, Area, [Date], Sales, COUNT(isstart) OVER( PARTITION BY Tenant ORDER BY [Date] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
FROM C1
 )
SELECT * FROM C2
```

Comment: `LAG` is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Neither is `COUNT` with `OVER ( ... ORDER BY )`

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer works well and the SQL Fiddle demo is great. However, it doesn't take into account the situation with multiple tenants.

I extended the SQL Fiddle answer and the link is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f36ae) for those people whose datasets comprise multiple tenants, simply by ensuring that tenant was present in each PARTITION BY and ORDER BY.